# Home Button Navigation not working properly

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment, android-homebutton

I am using action bar and fragments in my android app. I have home button in base activity and other fragments . These home buttons have different functionality.
while clicking fragment home button it forces a click in home button in the activity not in the current fragment. What should i do to avoid the click of back activity and perform current fragment home button click?

Comment: Do you please explain more in ui, your onOptionsItemSelected is MainActviry or inside fragment

Comment: woow .. my eyes are bleeding

Comment: please share the screenshots for better explanation